# Running the server with Flask run gives error but when using python app.py command the server is running as expected

Tags: python, flask

I'm getting this import error when using the command `flask run`.

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'APIs'`

here APIs refers to the
but when I'm using the command

`$ python app.py`

the server is running fine

The file structure is something sort of like this

```
|_ __init__.py 
|_ app.py
|_ APIs
   |_ __init__.py
   |_ router
      |_ __init__.py
      |_ router1.py
   |_service
      |_ __init__.py
      |_ service1.py
|_ Config
   |_ ...
|_ Exception
   |_ __init__.py
```

the content of all `__init__.py`  is empty

content of app.py

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_cors import CORS
from APIs.router.router1 import blueprint1
from APIs.router.router2 import blueprint2

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app,support_credentials=True)

app.register_blueprint(blueprint1)
app.register_blueprint(blueprint2)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(load_dotenv=True)
```

What do I have to do to get the server running even with `$ flask run` command?

I searched a bit. There, the suggested solution was adding the `__init__.py` inside APIs file but that didn't work in my case. BTW its working fine when running using `python app.py` even with out any `__init__.py` files.

Comment: You have `__init.py`, not `__init__.py`

Comment: thats my bad. I wrote wrong. its `__init__.py`

Answer (score 0):

It may be missing the FLASK_APP environment variable.
Try that:

```
export FLASK_APP=app.py
flask run
```

Comment: I used `set FLASK_APP=app.py` then used flask run but still getting same error

Answer (score 0):

I found out the problem and also have figured a work around. I dont know if thats how i am supposed to do it.

The problem was when I used `print(sys.path)` the path there is the parent folder of the project

```
|_ D: Drive
   |_ Projects
      |_ Flask
         |_ app.py
         | ...
         |_ APIs
            |_ ...
         |_ ...
```

lets say the folder structure is something of this sort. For the import of the API folder to work `sys.path` should have `D:\\Projects\Flask` but it has `D:\\Projects` for whatever reason. So added the current folder to the path list using `sys.path.append(os.getcwd())` so now the app is running as intended. But I still dont know whats the actual solution. I mean how to make it take the  `D:\\Projects\Flask` instead of `D:\\Projects`